# Npgsql reader type cast error (was: mono does not serialize complex types well)

Tags: .net, mono, remoting, npgsql

Am I right that serializing complex types is not implemented in Mono 2.4.2 yet, or have I made a mistake?

When I call my remote function, I get an error message:

```
Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke 
    (System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy rp, IMessage msg,
     System.Exception& exc, System.Object[]& out_args) [0x00000]
```

This is the remote function.
I got the same result when I use  `string[]`  instead.
`string` makes its way through well.

```
public List<string> GetHist()
{
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectStr);
    conn.Open();

    string cmd = "select * from history";
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(cmd, conn);
    List<string> s = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                s.Add(dr.GetString(i));
        }
        else
            s.Add("(hehe)");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return s;
}
```

The caller:

```
List<string> w = remoteClass.GetHist();
foreach (string s in w)
    Console.Write(s + ", ");
Console.WriteLine();
```

I found this at http://mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical :

> **What about serialization compatibility? Can I serialize an
>   object in Mono and deserialize it in
>   MS.NET or vice versa?**
>
> The serialization format implemented
>   in Mono is fully compatible with that
>   of MS.NET. However, having a
>   compatible format is not enough. In
>   order to successfully exchange
>   serialized objects, the corresponding
>   classes need to have the same internal
>   structure (that is, the same public
>   and private fields) in both sides.
>
> If you are serializing your own
>   classes, there is no problem, since
>   you have control over the assemblies
>   and classes being used for
>   serialization.
>
> However, if you are serializing
>   objects from the framework,
>   serialization compatibility is not
>   guaranteed, since the internal
>   structure of those objects may be
>   different. This compatibility is not
>   even guaranteed between different
>   MS.NET versions or Mono versions.
>
> Our policy is to do our best to make
>   the framework classes compatible
>   between Mono and MS.NET, however
>   sometimes this is not possible because
>   the internal implementation is too
>   different. Notice also that when we
>   change a class to make it compatible
>   with MS.NET, we lose compatibility
>   with older versions of Mono.
>
> In summary, if you are designing an
>   application that will run in different
>   environments and platforms which are
>   not under your control, and which need
>   to share serialized objects (either
>   using remoting, plain files, or
>   whatever), you must be careful with
>   what objects you share, and avoid
>   objects from the framework when
>   possible.
>
> (Notice that this only applies to
>   serializers based on the
>   System.Runtime.Serialization
>   framework, and does not apply to the
>   XmlSerializer).

However, it does not even work between mono-2.4.2 and another mono-2.4.2 application.

Comment: It seems the problem is not in the serialization, but the Npgsql reader class, GetString() or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Npgsql so I change the title.
These two lines should be equivalent I think, both should return a `string` but the first one does not work:

```
dr.GetString(i)
dr[i].ToString()
```

To make debugging even harder, .net remoting passed the error to the caller side.

Answer (score 0):

.net serialization does not do generics...yet...grrrrr.

Mono can be tricky but as of .net 2.0, string[] should work.  To be sure, try your code on windows.